# Why same height of screen doesn't display element in the same way?

Tags: android, screen

I try to make my app correct on each size of screen. I made many dimens files.

[image]

I try the xhdpi dimens file with nexus 4 (768 * 1280) emulator and a samsung A3 2016 - SMA310F (720 * 1280). I have a map and two buttons below the map. With the samsung, the buttons appear but with the emulator, the map is too big and the buttons disappear.

Do you have any idea why with the same size height, the screen is different ? Do I use the correct method ?

I tried to create a dimens file large-xhdpi : no access to it.

Thanks

Comment: can you post the XML of the layout which you are referring to?

Comment: @Mister Fisher if you find my answer useful you can up-vote it and accept it, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because different set of devices have different screen resolution and density. Therefore, the app will display layout differently accordingly for each screen size.

**Solution:**

An easier solution is to use weight attribute along with LinearLayout to solve the issue.

Follow the link for more info:
[weight in linearlayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear)

Answer (score 0):

Not only do Android devices come in different screen sizes, but their screens also have different pixel sizes.

To build a responsive UI please use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout).
This layout has many features that helps you create awesome and flexible UI. 
For example guidelines (with percentage support), chains and much more.

Also, you can set custom metrics to your activity or view,
**I do not think it is a good practice, but still good to know that it is possible and in some cases it may be useful**, check this out:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int dpi = 210; //for example
float scale = 1.10f; //for example
metrics.density = scale;
metrics.densityDpi = dpi;
metrics.scaledDensity = scale;
metrics.xdpi = dpi;
metrics.ydpi = dpi;
metrics.heightPixels = 480; //for example
metrics.widthPixels = 800; //for example
activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().setTo(metrics);
```

Good luck!

Comment: `I do not think it is a good practice` and you are damn right :)
I highly recommend to NOT do this. Instead go with the ConstraintLayout and with that the amount of dimensions can decrease

Comment: Addition to this answer: The key is to understand that screen resolution is unimportant. The important part is that you are working within densities. Some good documentations about
[screen sizes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes) and [screen densities](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities).

Comment: @WarrenFaith OK for constraintLayout... I try... If I work with ConstraintLayout, I don't need to use dimens file because I define size in the design, is it OK ?

Comment: Yes, I would add constants there like button height or so. Than you can use it in layouts everywhere but if you change it, you only change it in one place and it applies everywhere. I have only one dimens xml in my project which has dozens of screens and supports all possible screens and densities.

Comment: @WarrenFaith thanks for your answer. I begin to understand how to use constraintLayout. I have to test on many devices but it seems to be OK.